# Easiest way to find if a GET request does not find a resource

Tags: python, eve

In the [python-eve framework](http://python-eve.org/index.html), what would be the easiest way to find in a [post GET hook](http://python-eve.org/features.html#post-request-event-hooks) that the GET request failed to find any resources (for example, the given [filtering parameters](http://python-eve.org/features.html#filtering) failed to match any resources)?

Thanks!

Comment: What about the `resource` parameter? Isn't it empty in this case? Never tried Eve myself, but it seems really cool.

Comment: Wouldn't the `payload` parameter tell you that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `payload` is a Flask [`Response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Response) object, you can take profit of its features. One option would be to simply investigate the `_items` key, which, on a collection endpoint, returns the actual documents:

```
import json

def on_post_get(resoure, request, payload):
    # get the actual response json out of Flask Response
    json = json.loads(payload.get_data())

    documents = json['_items']
    assert(len(documents) == 0)

app = Eve()
app.on_post_GET += on_post_get

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: ...if the response is empty, would you have a suggestion on how I could easily manually instantiate a new resource (of the same type as the original request of course), populate it with some values and return it?  Or maybe I should open a new question for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the response header X-Total-Count within the hook.  If its value is 0, then it failed to find any resources.

To access this value, the invocation would look something like:

```
# Within run.py
app.on_fetched_resource_something += before_returning_something_items

# Within your hook module file
def before_returning_something_items(response):
    numRecs = int(response.headers.get("X-Total-Count"))
    if numRecs > 0:
        print "Found Something"
    else:
        print "Found Zilcho!"
```